# Как проверить находиться ли мышь на элементе и вернуть результат в виде логического типа?

Tags: javascript

В общем мне нужно выполнить вот такую проверку. 
Я в начале попытался сделать так ▼. Однако, значение приходит не в виде логического типа.

```
if (timeoutArea.mouseover !== true) {

    nextBtn.click();
};
```

Поэтому, я решил делать проверку, которая вернет true, если на элемент наводят мышью. Но она почему то не работает (разумеется в if утверждении я убирал `.mouseover`). Помогите пожалуйста

```
let timeoutArea = document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener('mouseover', isHover);

    function isHover(){
        return (timeoutArea === true);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У колбэк функции есть первый параметр - элемент, над которым свершается действие. У этого параметра куча других параметров. Один из них `target.tagName` где находится имя элемента, над которым происходит действие. Вот этим надо пользоваться.

```js
let timeoutArea = document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener('mouseover', isHover);

function isHover(e) {
  console.log(e.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA');
  return e.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA';
};
```

```html
<textarea id="slider">test</textarea>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!